# Get Store Information Magento 2.3.0

Tags: magento2, php, module, magento2.3

Using Magento 2.3.0 with php7.1

I'm trying to use this [module](https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-get-store-information-magento-2.html#step-1-declare-in-mageplaza_helloworld) to get store information.

I have modified the folder names as such

> ```
> app/code/Vendor/SiteInfo/Block/SiteInfo.php
> ```

And used the following code in **SiteInfo.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\SiteInfo\Block;
class SiteInfo extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_storeManager;    

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,        
        array $data = []
    )
    {        
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;        
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Get store identifier
     *
     * @return  int
     */
    public function getStoreId()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
    }

    /**
     * Get website identifier
     *
     * @return string|int|null
     */
    public function getWebsiteId()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
    }

    /**
     * Get Store code
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getStoreCode()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCode();
    }

    /**
     * Get Store name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getStoreName()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getName();
    }

    /**
     * Get current url for store
     *
     * @param bool|string $fromStore Include/Exclude from_store parameter from URL
     * @return string     
     */
    public function getStoreUrl($fromStore = true)
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentUrl($fromStore);
    }

    /**
     * Check if store is active
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isStoreActive()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->isActive();
    }
}
?>
```

**This is where I need help**, it then says

> Using the following script in the .phtml file and print the store
>   information.

```
echo $block->getStoreId() . '<br />';
echo $block->getStoreCode() . '<br />';
echo $block->getWebsiteId() . '<br />';
echo $block->getStoreName() . '<br />';
echo $block->getStoreUrl() . '<br />';
echo $block->isStoreActive() . '<br />';
```

I tried using it directly in the page using

```
<?php echo $block->getStoreName() . '<br />';?>
```

that just shows

**$block->getStoreName() . '
';**

---

So how do I go about this, for example if I want to show the "Store name" in a page or a block I've created from the admin panel, how do I go about using the echo script.

---

**Update:**

I've created a file

> storename.phtml

in

> app/code/Vendor/Siteinfo/view/frontend/templates

With this code

```
<?php 
/** @var \Vendor\ModuleName\Block\Hello $block */ 
?> 
<?php 
echo $block->getStoreName(); 
?>
```

and used this block on a page from admin panel

> {{block class="Vendor\SiteInfo\Block\SiteInfo" name="site-info"
>   as="site-info" template="Vendor_SiteInfo::storename.phtml" }}

flushed magento cache, and get this error

> "We're sorry, an error has occurred while generating this content."

This is [module](https://drive.google.com/file/d/121WNlpzOJZBSOCMan3EpqvAs3DWq_YZy/view?usp=sharing) I have created, that is at this path

> app/code

Comment: any error in log ?

Comment: No error in the logs

Comment: I have tried your code and it is working. in admin you are using `Vendor` instead of `Website` ?

Comment: I have shared the module I have created above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are mainly 2 issue.

1. Your Registration.php is placed at wrong place
   Currently it is placed at

   > Vendor/Siteinfo/etc/registration.php

**it should be:**

> Vendor/Siteinfo/registration.php

2. Wrong Vendor name is defined in registration.php
3. Wrong Vendor name in module.xml

   **Please follow below**

   Create

   > app/code/Vendor/Siteinfo/registration.php

   ```
   <?php
   \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
       \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
   'Vendor_Siteinfo',
   __DIR__
   );
   ```

   > app/code/Vendor/Siteinfo/etc/module.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
   <module name="Vendor_Siteinfo" setup_version="1.0.0">
   </module>
   ```

   > app/code/Vendor/Siteinfo/Block/Siteinfo.php

   ```
   <?php
   namespace Vendor\Siteinfo\Block;
   class Siteinfo extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
   {    
   public function __construct(
       \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
       array $data = []
   )
   {            
       parent::__construct($context, $data);
   }

   /**
    * Get store identifier
    *
    * @return  int
    */
   public function getStoreId()
   {
       return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
   }

   /**
    * Get website identifier
    *
    * @return string|int|null
    */
   public function getWebsiteId()
   {
       return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
   }

   /**
    * Get Store code
    *
    * @return string
    */
   public function getStoreCode()
   {
       return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCode();
   }

   /**
    * Get Store name
    *
    * @return string
    */
   public function getStoreName()
   {
       return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getName();
   }

   /**
    * Get current url for store
    *
    * @param bool|string $fromStore Include/Exclude from_store parameter from URL
    * @return string     
    */
   public function getStoreUrl($fromStore = true)
   {
       return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentUrl($fromStore);
   }

   /**
    * Check if store is active
    *
    * @return boolean
    */
   public function isStoreActive()
   {
       return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->isActive();
   }
   }
   ?>
   ```

   > app/code/Vendor/Siteinfo/view/frontend/templates/storename.phtml

   ```
   <?php echo $block->getStoreName(); ?>
   ```

   After that you need to run:

   php bin/magento setup:upgrade

   php bin/magento cache:flush

Finally call:

> {{block class="Vendor\Siteinfo\Block\Siteinfo" name="site-info" as="site-info" template="Vendor_Siteinfo::storename.phtml" }}

You can download module at [GitHub](https://github.com/pawankparmar/Siteinfo)

Comment: Have done exactly as you have listed, the config end tag was missing on the module.xml, I added that and ran upgrade, the module is enabled under etc/config.php, however I'm getting this error   "Error filtering template: Invalid block type: Vendor\Siteinfo\Block\Siteinfo"

Comment: From exception log [2019-01-09 18:56:02] main.CRITICAL: Invalid block type: Vendor\Siteinfo\Block\Siteinfo {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\LocalizedException(code: 0): Invalid block type: Vendor\\Siteinfo\\Block\\Siteinfo at /home/xyz/m230.xyz.com/Vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php:275, ReflectionException(code: -1): Class Vendor\\Siteinfo\\Block\\Siteinfo does not exist at /home/xyz/m230.xyz.com/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:19)"} []

Comment: Your block name file should be `Siteinfo.php`. I have upload module on github, Please download and it. I have tested and it s working.If still have any issue, let me know.

Comment: Thank you very much Pawan, much appreciated, it works! :-)

Comment: Glad to know. Welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want this in block from admin panel.
Call from block or from CMS page like this

```
{{block class="Mynamespace\Mymodule\Block\SiteInfo" name="site-info" as="site-info" template="Magento_Theme::siteinfo.phtml" }}
```

It will call the function from related class.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> In order to use the following **`block scripts`**
>   you need to create a **`template`**
>
> Example: Create a template **`hello.phtml`** to your custom module following the namespace structure below
>
> **Vendor\ModuleName\view\frontend\templates\hello.phtml**

```
<?php
/** @var \Vendor\ModuleName\Block\Hello $block */
?>
<?php echo $block->getStoreName(); ?>
```

Comment: I've created a storename.phtml file in app/code/vendor/Siteinfo/view/frontend/templates

With this code <?php
/** @var \Vendor\ModuleName\Block\Hello $block */
?>
<?php echo $block->getStoreName(); ?>

and used this block on a page from admin panel

{{block class="vendor\SiteInfo\Block\SiteInfo" name="site-info" as="site-info" template="Magento_Theme::storename.phtml" }}

flushed magento cache, and get this error

"We're sorry, an error has occurred while generating this content."

Should I run a upgrade from SSH?

Comment: can you post your code for the page in admin in your post above. I will check. no need to run upgrade from ssh