# Call to a member function get() on null

Tags: magento2, php, object-manager

I am new to magento 2 and i have tried to get the store id.
Here is my code simplifyed:

```
class Mage{  
   private static $_objectManger;
   public  function __construct(
      \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager
   )
   {
      self::$_objectManager = $objectmanager;
   }
   public static function  getStore(){
      return self::$_objectManger->get("\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface");
   }
}
```

And in my .phtml file i try to call it like this:

```
$store_id= Mage::getStore()->getStoreId();
echo $store_id;
```

and i get this error message exactly at this line:

```
return self::$_objectManger->get("\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface");
```

So why does this doesnt work?

Comment: here i show you full code

Comment: @Msquare is right. i used this code in my module. it's works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Module **Block** file add below code.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;
class Module extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_storeManager;    

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,        
        array $data = []
    )
    {        
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;        
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Get store identifier
     *
     * @return  int
     */
    public function getStoreId()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
    }
}
```

In your **PHTML** file

```
echo $block->getStoreId();
```

Comment: where is the block file

Comment: You can create it in your module.

Comment: how should i name the php file?

Comment: Have you created a module?

Comment: My vendor name is `Steiner` and my Module is called `All` and it has currently these folders: `etc` `view` `composer.json` and `registration.php` and i have created an folder named `block`

Comment: please have a look at https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/257091/get-store-information-magento-2-3-0/257284#257284

Comment: download whole code from https://github.com/pawankparmar/Siteinfo

Comment: you have this file https://github.com/pawankparmar/Siteinfo/blob/master/Vendor/Siteinfo/Block/Siteinfo.php in your module

Comment: or you can simply get the storeId In your PHTML file with using Object Manager,
Check replace this code in your PHTML file $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();        
$storeManager  = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$storeID       = $storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId();

Comment: i used `objectManager` and it worked but i readed alot i should not use it directly thats why i want to use it like this

Comment: That's why I answered with Block file creation

Comment: well i have done it and i get no errors, but i also get no result, result is just empty

Comment: to verify that your PHTML load or not print some text in your PHTML file

Comment: Thank you, i have forgot to change the `class=""` in my CMS block code, it works now

Answer (score 0):

In magento 2 you should never use object manager to instantiate new objects. Always use dependency injection instantiating your object in the constructor.

In your phtml file you have magento 1 code.

This shoud look something like this:

**BLOCK:**

```
<?php
/**
 * @category    Magento 2
 * @author      Mattia Kozianowski
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\MyBlock;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

/**
 * Class MyClass
 *
 * @package Vendor\Module;
 */
class MyClass extends Template
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * MyClass constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        Template\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Store\Api\Data\StoreInterface
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function getStore()
    {
        return $this->storeManager->getStore();
    }
}
```

Then place your block specifying the template (phtml) using layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!--
/**
 * @category    Magento 2
 * @author      Mattia Kozianowski
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\MyBlock\MyClass" template="Vendor_Module::myfile.phtml"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Call your method in phtml:

```
<?php
/**
 * @category    Magento 2
 * @author      Mattia Kozianowski
 */

/** @var $block \Vendor\Module\Block\MyBlock\MyClass */
?>

<h1><?= $block->getStore()->getName()?></h1>
```

You can find some more information here: https://www.cloudways.com/blog/magento-2-layouts-blocks-templates/

Answer (score 0):

**This is tested code**

**Vendor/Siteinfo/etc/registration.xml**

***registration.php***

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Siteinfo',
    __DIR__
);
```

**Vendor/Siteinfo/etc/module.xml**

***module.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Siteinfo" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

**Vendor/Siteinfo/etc/frontend/routes.xml**

***routes.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route frontName="siteinfo" id="siteinfo">
            <module name="Vendor_Siteinfo"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**Vendor/Siteinfo/Block/Siteinfo.php**

***Siteinfo.php***

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Siteinfo\Block;

class Siteinfo extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function getStoreInfo()
    {
        echo $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId() . '<br />';
        // by default: URL_TYPE_LINK is returned
        echo $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl() . '<br />';
        echo $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_WEB) . '<br />';
        echo $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_DIRECT_LINK) . '<br />';
        echo $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . '<br />';
        echo $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_STATIC) . '<br />';
        echo $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getUrl('product/33') . '<br />';
        echo $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentUrl(false) . '<br />';
        echo $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseMediaDir() . '<br />';
        echo $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseStaticDir() . '<br />';
    }
}
```

**Vendor/Siteinfo/view/frontend/templates/storename.phtml**

***storename.phtml***

```
<h2>Store Info </h2>
<?php $block->getStoreInfo(); ?>
```

**Vendor/Siteinfo/Controller/Storeinfo/Storeinfo.php**

***Storeinfo.php***

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Siteinfo\Controller\Storeinfo;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Storeinfo extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    protected $resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    }
}
```

**Vendor/Siteinfo/view/frontend/layout/siteinfo_storeinfo_storeinfo.xml**

***siteinfo_storeinfo_storeinfo.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>SiteInfo</title>
    </head>
      <body>
        <block class="Vendor/Siteinfo/Block/Siteinfo" name="storelocator_index_index" template="Vendor_Siteinfo::storename.phtml" />
      </body>
</page>
```

run magento command

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento c:c
php bin/magento c:f
```

now you check it into your url

> http://example/m234/siteinfo/storeinfo/storeinfo