# Get store name and store url, email address magento 2

Tags: magento2

I want to get store name and store URL in magento 2.

https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-get-store-information-magento-2.html

I tried to use `Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface` and get the store with this code

```
$this->storeManager->getStore()->getName()
```

However, this always returns the string `Default Store View` instead of my store name

I tried  `$this->storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentUrl(true)` to get the store URL but there is no `getCurrentUrl` in the StoreInterface;

Comment: check this link - http://www.blogtreat.com/get-store-information-in-magento-2/

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work with $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getName();

Comment: share your full code

Comment: lease have a look at : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/257091/get-store-information-magento-2-3-0/257284#257284

Answer (score 0):

Can you check this and tell me if it works or not

```
$om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$manager = $om->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$store = $manager->getStore(null)->getName();
```

Thanks in advance,